# Why is omitting functions from React's useEffect dependency list unsafe?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to the [React Hook FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies),

> It is **only** safe to omit a function from the dependency list if nothing
>   in it (or the functions called by it) references props, state, or
>   values derived from them.

The FAQ then goes on to give an example where the function is ommitted and says that the code contains a bug. However, the FAQ never mentions what the bug is.

I made a similar example where I create a function that makes use of two pieces of state. That function is then called from a useEffect hook that only has one piece of the state in its dependency list. However, even though there is the promised ESLint warning for a missing dependency, the function and the useEffect hook work as expected.

[Code sandbox of the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-mtgh4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

#### Intended semantics:

- The alert is displayed when the greet button is clicked (direct function call)
- The alert is displayed when the "greeting" state is changed (via useEffect)
- The alert *is not* displayed when the name changes.
- Whenever the greeting is displayed, the last specified name is used.

#### Code:

```
export function UseEffectEx(props) {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState("Hello");
  const [name, setName] = useState("John");
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(Math.random());

  function greet() {
    alert(`${greeting}, ${name}.`);
  }

  useEffect(
    function greetOnGreetingChange() {
      greet();
    },
    [greeting]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={greet}>Greet</button>
      <button onClick={() => setGreeting("Hello")}>
        set greeting to 'Hello'
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setGreeting("Goodbye")}>
        set greeting to 'Goodbye'
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setName("John")}>set name to 'John'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName("Jane")}>set name to 'Jane'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setRandomNumber(Math.random())}>
        generate random
      </button>
      <p>Random number = ${randomNumber}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

All of the intended semantics are satisfied. Curcially, using the buttons to change the name state doesn't trigger the alert, but the correct name is always used when the alert is triggered.

#### ESLint warning

The above code produces the promised **react-hooks/exhaustive-deps** warning on the dependency list for useEffect(). The warning says tat the hook is missing a dependency for `greet()`. The auto-fix for the warning is to add greet as a dependency.

```
  useEffect(
    function greetOnGreetingChange() {
      greet();
    },
    [greeting, greet]
  );
```

However, this produces another ESLint error, this time on the `greet()` function. The error states that the function is being called on every render. Clicking the *generate random* button confirms this unintended behavior. ESLint suggests that the `greet()` function should be wrapped in a `useCallback` effect, such as:

```
  const greet = useCallback(function greet() {
    alert(`${greeting}, ${name}.`)
  }, [greeting]);
```

But in turtles all the way down sort of scenario, ESLint complains that the useCallback effect is missing the `name` dependency. Adding that dependency breaks the intended semantics, since the alert will now trigger anytime the *name* state is updated.

#### Solutions?

This is a simple, somewhat contrived example, but it occurs frequently in mulitple code bases I've been working on. The scenario is simple. You have some state using function inside a component. The function is called in mutliple places within the component, both inside and outside a useEffect hook. You want the useEffect hook to only call the function when a single piece of prop or state changes.

React's documentation suggests the best solution is to move the function inside the useEffect hook. But this would prevent it from being used in other places within the component. The next suggestion is to include the fucntion in the dependnecy list, and wrap it with a useCallback() hook if needed. However,in many cases this either introduces unwelcomed behavior, or simply boots the ESLint error up to useCallback().

What is the "*bug*" in the original code that React wants to guard against? Is there another solution other than disabling the ESLint inspection?

Comment: From Dan Abramov himself:   https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [Dan Abramov Use Effect article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) (provided by @Bennett Dams), there are no great solutions.

#### Question: What is the bug in the code?

The bug that the ESList warning is guarding against is that the effect won't fire when the name state is changed. However, since this very behavior is intended, the bigger issue is that the semantics of the code depend on state changes sometimes sometimes causing an update, and other times not. This seems to go against the tide of React Hooks.

#### Question: Ok, but I want to do it anyway. Is there a solution other than disabling the ESLint warning?

Yes - although a little ugly, using `useReducer` can achieve the desired semantics. The code below is ugly because we are using a reducer to trigger a function instead of using it as intended, which is to update state.

```js
function Example(props) {
  const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState('Hello');
  const [name, setName] = useState('John');
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber] = useState(Math.random());
  const [_, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});

  function greet() {
    alert(`${greeting}, ${name}.`)
  }

  function reducer(state, action) {
    if (action.type === 'alert') {
      greet();
    }
    return state;
  }


  useEffect(function greetOnGreetingChange() {
    dispatch({type: 'alert'})
  }, [dispatch, greeting]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setGreeting('Hello')}>set greeting to 'Hello'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setGreeting('Goodbye')}>set greeting to 'Goodbye'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName('John')}>set name to 'John'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName('Jane')}>set name to 'Jane'</button>
      <button onClick={() => setRandomNumber(Math.random())} >generate random</button>
      <button onClick={() => greet()}>greet</button>
      <p>Random number = ${randomNumber}</p>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Since `dispatch` is guaranteed to always remain consistent across renders, the effect will only trigger on changes to *greeting* state, while the alert will still capture and display any changes to the *name* state.